# Как читать заключение переменных в фигурные скобки и функции ()()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Смотрел в интернете пример применения Redux и там увидел такой код:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { value } = state.counter;

  return { value };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxCounter);
```

`ReduxCounter` - это react-компонент.
Память подсказывает что в JS 2 строка записана в ECMA 6 и это эквивалент:

```
const value = state.counter.value;
```

но вопрос в возвращаемом результате, который тоже заключен в фигурные скобки `return { value };` ??

И второй вопрос - как понять запись `connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxCounter)`?
Интересует последовательность действий понятным языком.

Answer (score 2):

`return { value };`  - это всё равно что `return {value: value};`

`connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxCounter)`:
Функциия `connect(mapStateToProps)` возвращает другую функцию, которая тут же вызывается с аргументами `(ReduxCounter)`

```js
function a(){
  return function(value){
      return {value} 
  }
}

console.log(
  a()(2)
)
```